# Accessing a DB on a different server from a stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I've often needed to do a SELECT for instance on a table in another DB which I've been doing as follows:

```
SELECT MyColumn FROM MyOtherDB.dbo.MyOtherTable WHERE Conditions
```

Of course this will only work if the DB is on the same server. Is there a way this can be achieved if the two DBs are on different servers, let's say 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2?

Comment: Read about `Openquery and Openrowset` on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create link to that server with [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx). After that you should create a [synonym](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx). Than you can use that synonym with in your query.